# POST data dynamic select not sending

Tags: javascript, php, forms

So I have a form where it should be posting both the country selected and one of the states or cities from either drop down, it just posts both selections under country despite the names of these being different both in the form and in the post data on the php mailer script.

so here is the form:

```
<select style="width: 64%;" name="country" class="country">
     <option value="UK">UK</option>
     <option value="US">US</option>
</select>


<select style="width: 64%;"  class='city' name="city">

</select></center>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var ukCities = ['Avon', 'Bedfordshire', 'Berkshire'];
var usCities = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];

$(document).on("change", "select.country", function() {
    var country = $("select.country").val();
    var cities;
    if(country === 'UK'){
        cities = ukCities;
    }
    else{
        cities = usCities;
    }
    $("select.city").empty();
    $.each(cities, function(index, element){
            $("select.city").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", country).text(element));
    });
});
$("select.country").val('UK').trigger('change');
```

And here these are what should be being posted form the php mialer script:

```
$mail->Body = 
'Name: ' . $_POST["assocName"] . 
'<br>Email: ' . $_POST["firstName"] . 
'<br>Tel: ' . $_POST["lastName"] . 
'<br>Position: ' . $_POST["position"]  .
'<br>Country: ' . $_POST["country"] . 
'<br>City: ' . $_POST["city"] . 
'<br>Community Type: ' . $_POST["comType"] . 
'<br>Dwellings: ' . $_POST["dwellings"] . 
'<br>Email: ' . $_POST["emailAddress"];
```

When I select UK and a city for example, the email comes through giving me the city for both Country and city.

Comment: You're vulnerable to XSS

Comment: What do you mean "giving me the city for both Country and city"? And where do you call the PHP file?

Comment: I have only given you the part of the form that is causing me a problem. The form goes thorugh fine and we receive the email, the issue being that if I select UK for example and then Select Bedfordshire and submit the form, the email I receive shows me that I answeered UK to both country and city

Comment: @true that's all kind of helpful Sir but it isn't helping me solve this issue?

Comment: @user3520443 you have 2 problems now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's giving you city for both Country and City because of this:

```
$("select.city").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", country).text(element));
```

You need to set the `value` to `element` and not `country` so it reads:

```
$("select.city").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", element).text(element));
```

HTML doesn't even see what's in between the `option` tags, only what their `value` is.  That's what gets POSTed